# How to try an app on a tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am doing some applications using Android + Eclipse to run on tablets. I have had too much trouble with the tablet emulator, so I would like to try my code (apps) on a real tablet. How can I do this? I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3. Do I need to install the adt-bundle on it?
I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: You do not need to have the adt-bundle installed on it. All you need is usb driver for your tablet installed on the PC/laptop. You can check if the system detects your device by typing **adb devices** in cmd/shell. If List of devices attached isn't empty (like: xxxxxxx device), then it's been detected and you will be prompted by Eclipse to use it when running the app.

Comment: I plugged in the USB cable and the driver for the tablet installed automatically. I enabled the USB debugging in the tablet under the Developer options. I've also installed the Android version to 4.1.2 which is the one that the tablet has. When selecting Run As, I select Run Configurations, then Target, and choose to run on Active Devices and I get this error: No active compatible AVD's or devices found. I relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD. Even though I can see the tablet connected and ready to use, my app is not running on it. What else could I check?

Comment: in your manifest file what are your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion values?Does your app support your tablet?

Comment: These are my values in the manifest file:
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
I coded this app specifically for tablets. I have tried several emulators with no success and decided to give it a try on a real tablet. How can I check to see if my app and my tablet are compatible?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

11 is for android 3.0 and 19 for 4.4 so theoretically you shouldn't have a problem. Does your app require hardware not available in your tablet(some kind of sensor maybe)?

Comment: Not sure about that. What I realized was that the tablet is Android version 4.1.2. The tablet is connected as a device on the laptop but I can't see it as an active device inside Eclipse. This tablet is a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 and it supposedly allows users to try code on it. What else I need to enable in order to run the app on it?

Comment: try restarting eclipse. Disonnect the tablet and connect it again. Follow the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) . Unfortunately there is nothing more I can think of

Comment: Thank you Mike. You have been very helpful. I will do this one more time, because I am running out of options.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

You just need a usb cable to connect your device to your pc.Go to the above link for more info

Comment: Oh thank you. I have already connected the tablet to my laptop, but after that I don't know how to proceed. I also was able to put the folder with my code onto the tablet. But how to run it... that is where I am now.

Comment: run the app with the tablet connected.The tablet should appear in the device manager.Choose from the device manager to run the app with the tablet and that's all.You need to follow the instructions in the link first by changing some settings in your tablet

Answer (score 1):

check this it may help you [Run on a Real Device](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)

Here is a copy paste, but check the link it's really good and well explained :

If you have a real Android-powered device, here's how you can install and run your app:

1-Plug in your device to your development machine with a USB cable. If you're developing on Windows, you might need to install the appropriate USB driver for your device. For help installing drivers, see the [OEM USB Drivers document](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html).

2-Enable USB debugging on your device.

On most devices running Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.
On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.

**Note**: On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer options is hidden by default. 
To make it available, go to Settings > About phone and tap Build number seven times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

**To run the app from Eclipse:**

1-Open one of your project's files and click Run  from the toolbar.
2-In the Run as window that appears, select Android Application and click OK.
Eclipse installs the app on your connected device and starts it.

Or to run your app from a command line:

1-Change directories to the root of your Android project and execute:

```
ant debug
```

2- Make sure the Android SDK platform-tools/ directory is included in your PATH environment variable, then execute:

```
adb install bin/MyFirstApp-debug.apk
```

3-On your device, locate MyFirstActivity and open it.

Comment: you are welcome ... and don't hesitate to check the answer if it answer your question